# Решение задачи на Delphi,C++,C#,Python

Tags: javascript, c#, c++, python, delphi

Составьте логическую функцию проверки, является ли параметр простым числом.

Comment: Как предполагается получить b для введённого n ?

Answer (score 1):

Немного ускорим решение Ildar'а:

```
bool is_prime(unsigned long long n)
{
    if (n%2 == 0) return false;
    for(int i = 3; i*i <= n; i+=2)
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Ну, а 2<sup>32</sup>+1 = 641*6700417 :)

Comment: круто, спасибо!)

Comment: @harry Не очень разбираюсь в C(извините). Что необходимо "дописать", чтобы код компилировался.(/sorry)

Comment: А разве не будет ещё быстрее, если перед циклом вычислить `int x = n/2` и затем это значение использовать как граничное в условии `i <= x`?

Comment: @zed Не понял... вы хотите сказать, что `n/2` меньше корня из `n`?

Comment: Нет, я про то, чтобы возведение `i` в квадрат в for убрать из цикла: `for(int i = 3; i <= x; i+=2)`

Comment: Ну и увеличить тем самым цикл от корня из n до n/2. Например, т = 1000000. Вы предлагаете идти до 500000, я - до 1000...

Comment: Хорошо, тогда надо сделать вот так: `int x = sqrt(n);` - будет ходить до 1000 и не будет возведения в квадрат на каждой итерации.

Comment: @zed Сравните как-нибудь скорости целочисленных операций и операции с плавающей точкой - будете удивлены :) Соглашусь даже, что, возможно, это и будет быстрее - но вряд ли больше процентов 10%. А вообще, всегда предпочитаю использовать целочисленную арифметику, и плавающую точку применять только там, где иначе - ну никак...

Answer (score 0):

вы там что то намудрили, вот алгоритм реализующую проверку простоты числа:

```
bool prime(unsigned __int64 n) {
  for (int i = 2;i <= sqrt(n);++i) {
    if (n % i == 0)
        return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Число же в `int` по условию не вмещается.

Comment: @zed исправлено

Comment: Ускоряется минимум в 2 раза. И лучше не использовать плавающую точку (`sqrt`) - случаи, они всякие бывают :)

Comment: @Ildar, простите, случайно не в тот ответ было ткнулся в "править"...